# How to tag services by path in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

In a Symfony application, how can I automatically tag all classes in a specific directory?

In `services.yaml` I have:

```yaml
services:
    App\Service\TaggableServicesDirectory\:
        resource: '../src/Service/TaggableServicesDirectory/*'
        tags: ['app.my_tag']
```

However, those services don't get actually tagged. I can see that by running `bin/console debug:container --tag=app.my_tag`, which returns an error about not existing tag.

I have also tried tagging by parent class:

```yaml
services:
    _instanceof:
        App\Service\TaggableServicesDirectory\AbstractTaggableService:
            tags: ['app.my_tag']
```

which works as expected, so I know that path and tag name are correct. However, tagging by parent class is not ideal for my use case.

**EDIT: the configuration from the first example works as expected on a new Symfony project, so it's likely some other incorrect configuration on my main project.**

Comment: Just drop the * from the end of your first resource example and it should work.  `resource: '../src/Service/TaggableServicesDirectory/'`. This is how controllers used to be tagged.  I even made a quick test under 6.2.  If it still fails then check for typos.

Comment: I created myself a new Symfony project to test it and apparently it works in all cases: with `*`, without, and without even a trailing slash `/`. So probably some other configuration is incorrect in my main project. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I confirmed that, at least in 6.2, the ending of the resource string does not really matter.  Always good to learn something new.  Might try `debug:container TaggedService` just to rule out the possibility that the services were excluded.  And check to see if additional configuration (possibly a compiler pass) might be replacing the tagged definition.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you can't specify the directory as in your example. But you can do it manually by specifying class name and tag individually for each object.

```
services:
    App\Service\TaggableServicesDirectory\ClassOne:
        tags: ['app.my_tag']
```

However, to bind the tag automatically, use the interface as recommended in the [symfony documentation](https://Then%20implement%20this%20interface%20in%20your%20classes.).

```
#[AutoconfigureTag('app.my_tag')]
interface CustomTagInterface
{
    // ...
}
```

Then implement this interface in your classes.

Comment: Your opening statement about not being able to tag by directory is objectively wrong.  It is how controllers used to be tagged.  The poster just had a minor syntax error.  I agree that tagging by interface is perhaps recommended but maybe there is a reason why the poster did not want to do so.